# Google-maps-react doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

I have MapContainer:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
export class MapContainer extends Component {
componentDidUpdate(props) {
    this.loadMap();
}
loadMap() {
    if (this.props && this.props.google) {
        const {google} = this.props;
        const maps = google.maps;
        const mapRef = this.refs.map;
        const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(mapRef);
        const mapConfig = Object.assign({}, {
            center: {lat: 50.4418782, lng: 30.5107196},
            zoom: 15,
        })
        this.map = new maps.Map(node, mapConfig);
            addMarker({lat: 50.4418782,lng: 30.5107196});
            function addMarker(coords) {
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: coords,
                    map: this.map
                });
            }
     }
 }



render() {
    const style = {
        width: '100%',
        height: '40rem',
        margin: '2rem auto'
    };

    return (
        <div ref="map" style={style}>
            loading map...
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MapContainer;
```

When it start I have TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyQeH.png)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In `React` functions are not automatically bound to component instance ([documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)), they need to be explicitly bound.  You could utilize `bind` function for that matter,in the provided example the line:

```
addMarker({lat: 50.4418782,lng: 30.5107196});
```

needs to be replaced with:

```
addMarker.bind(this)({ lat: 50.4418782, lng: 30.5107196 });
```